# html button with custom corners

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, rounded-corners

I'm currently designing a navigation bar for a website using Bootstrap. There is a main navigation bar and a second one directly under the first, see image:

[image]

I managed to round the corners of the button bottom with simple CSS but for the top corners I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in CSS/jQuery or with an additional plugin?

EDIT:

HTML for the button is:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn navbar-btn second-navbar-button">
    <span class="mdi mdi-eye second-navbar-icon"></span>
    <span class="second-navbar-name">&nbsp;Overview</span>
</button>
```

The CSS for the button looks like the following

```
.second-navbar-button {
  font-size: 26px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ec9f14;
  margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;}
```

There is space between the buttons so manipulating the corners of the adjacent button won't work, afaik.

Cheers,

Trammy

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you look carefully, the rounded edges on the left and right(top) , could actually come from rounded edges on the adjacent buttons.

Comment: you can achieve this using the `before` and `after` pseudo-element , put some code so i can help you more

Comment: Thank you Anas, I've added the CSS code for the buttons now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```css
.button{
    border:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:0;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    margin:30px;
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}
.button:after,
.button:before{
    content:'';
    width:40px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-3px;
    border-top:0;
}
.button:after{
    border-left:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 0;
    left:-41px;
}
.button:before{
    border-right:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 0 5px;
    right:-41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks pedram. This helped a lot and pointed me in the right direction.